# Central moments of residuals in nonlinear regression fit

Tags: regression, residuals

I am using nonlinear regression to fit data. Can I use central moments of residuals to estimate the quality of my fit? Especially 2nd central moment, third and fourth?
I did not find any literature about higher order central moments used for residuals.
Is good fit characterized by zero higher order central moments? (I mean second, third and fourth order)

Comment: I'd use residual plots to investigate the quality of the fit; a particular set of weird moments could be caused by all manner of different things but suitable displays will help you identify which issues you actually have. For example, residuals vs fitted; if that's okay some indicate of scale (e.g. square roots of absolute residuals vs fitted); if that's okay, some indicator of distributional shape (e.g. normal Q-Q plots); then probably something to find high leverage points that might be outliers. By the same token a very ordinary-looking set of moments may happen with a poor model.